# How to use Flatten to a specific element of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have a list `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, ...}`. I want to make the list look like `{1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, ...}`. I am doing this way:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}};
list2 = Flatten[list[[1]], 1];
list3 = Append[list2, list[[2]]]
```

This is giving me the correct result. But is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Or `FlattenAt[list, 1]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To flatten the first list in a list of lists:

```
Append @@ list
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, {4, 5}}
> ```

```
{##& @@ #,##2}& @@ list
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, {4, 5}}
> ```

In general, in addition to `FlattenAt[list, 1]` suggested by Rohit in comments, you can use

```
MapAt[Splice, list, {1}] (* in versions 12.1+ *)

MapAt[Apply[Sequence], list, {1}]

MapAt[Sequence&, list, {1, 0}]

ReplacePart[list, {1, 0} -> Sequence]

l = list; l[[1]] = Splice[l[[1]]]; l

l = list; l[[1,0]] = Sequence; l
```

Comment: Thanks. all are working accurately except MapAt[Splice, list, {1}]. I am getting error : Splice::string: String expected at position 1 in Splice[{1,2,3}].

Comment: @ArghyaDatta, you need version 12.1 for `MapAt[Splice, list, {1}]`  to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {1}};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[a_ :> Sequence @@ a, 1] @ list
```

{1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, {1}}

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list /. {{a__}, b__} :> {a, b}
```

{1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, {1}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {1}};
```

---

Using `Insert`:

```
Insert[{##}[[1]], Splice@{##2}, -1] & @@ list

(*{1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, {1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, delete the head (part 0) of part 1 using [`Delete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html)

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}};

Delete[list,{1,0}]

(* {1,2,3,{4,5}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `MapAt` and `Splice`:

```
MapAt[Splice, 1] @ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}
```

> {1, 2, 3, {4, 5}}